# CloudSQL Replicas Load Balance

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When read replica is created 2 IPs are assigned to the master and the read replica.

So when an application is connected to the CloudSQL using master IP, does it only use the master instance or is it connected to both instances?

Does the CloudSQL load balance the traffic among the replicas or do the application have to manually connect to the replicas?

Is there a way to achieve this without manually connecting to each instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So when an application is connected to the CloudSQL using master IP,
> does it only use the master instance or is it connected to both
> instances?

When the client is connected to the IP address of the master, it is only connected to the master.

> Does the CloudSQL load balance the traffic among the replicas or do
> the application have to manually connect to the replicas?

Google Cloud SQL does not load balance. If you wish to distribute read-only traffic, the client must perform that function.

> Is there a way to achieve this without manually connecting to each
> instance?

No. The client must connect to the masters and replicas to distribute read-only traffic. Logic must be present to send write traffic to the master only.

I wrote an in-depth article on this topic:

[Google Cloud SQL for MySQL – Connection Security, High Availability and Failover](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-sql-for-mysql-connection-security-high-availability-and-failover/)